# Why is express.static not serving my public folder?

Tags: express

Im trying to serve my public folder and I dont know why my express.static line isnt working.

This is what my public folder looks like:

```js
public
-images
---img1.png
---blah.png
-js
---app.js
-pages
---index.html
---blah.html
---blah.html
-styles
---styles.css
```

This is what my code looks like:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port: ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
let app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port: ${PORT}`);
});
```

You need to assign express() to app for it to work like I did.
Accept the answer if it works thanks :).